# Best approach of development of one page web app with screens (before and after registration)

Tags: web-applications, dart, dart-html

I need to develop an interactive mock-up of website, it should have different interface (dialogs) before user registration and after user registration, also after registration it should have the list of pictures and html games. I like Dart (and created my own libraries), but I didn't use Dart Angular or Polymer. Is it a good approach to create all dialogs (interface) and to send it before user registration? Or how to create web app with dynamically loadable multi screens? Thanks.

Main idea / request - to download separate parts (screens) from a server and to provide less information before registration / login .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Angular and Polymer a set of powerful ready-to-use components are available, which makes it easy to build web applications but there is no need to use them. Depending on your requirements it might be easier to use just plain `dart:html`.
You also don't need to download parts from the server. Just create functions which dynamically create components (HTML with event handlers) and add or remove them on demand to/from the DOM.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Just to clarify - is it better to have all-in-one solution than (for example) two html-landing page (app): one for not-registered users and one for registered/logged users? Yes, I am going to use plain dart:html library.

Comment: Usually one application is better. There might be situations where two separate landing pages might have advantages but I can't think of one just yet. If it is for security then it's the wrong reason. You have to enforce security on the server.

Comment: Thank you very much Günter for your explanation! I understood.